# Unable to change column and alter index in pt-online-schema-change

Tags: mysql, database-schema, alter, percona

I'm trying to alter a column and change a few indexes on a table at the same time. To do this, I'm using `pt-online-schema-change` so that it can happen online, but I'm getting an error:

> Error altering new table `db`.`_test_table_new`: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Key column 'foo' doesn't exist in table [for Statement "ALTER TABLE `db`.`_test_table_new` ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo, bar), DROP INDEX test_table_foo_idx, DROP_INDEX test_table_bar_idx, CHANGE COLUMN foo foo2 VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL;"] at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 9040.

The table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `foo` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
    `bar` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY `test_table_id_idx` (`id`),
    KEY `test_table_foo_idx` (`foo`, `id`),
    KEY `test_table_bar_idx` (`bar`, `id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In essence, I'm trying the following:

```
ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo, bar)
DROP INDEX test_table_foo_idx,
DROP INDEX test_table_bar_idx,
CHANGE COLUMN foo foo2 TEXT;
```

I'm able to do the index alteration and column alteration separately (but then I would need to copy all my data twice, would prefer doing it only once), but if I add the two together, it gives an error. It feels like I'm missing something obvious; any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - But why don't you rename the column in a regular way (without pt-online-schema-change)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm actually also trying to do an alter on the column: I want a different type. But I was able to reduce the issue to just renaming. Smaller dataset needed to reproduce, I suppose. The reason for percona toolkit is that I want everything to happen online, and able to be rate limited.

Comment: Still not sure if that helps.. but look at the [table here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html). Since MySQL 5.6 no "table rebuild" is required for renaming a column.

Comment: True, but I do actually require a table rebuild for *changing the data type on the column*.  My specific issue at the moment is with the `ALTER TABLE` syntax not seeming to work in pt-online-schema-change, as a hard requirement is being able to control the resources for the process, and we don't have cgroups. I'll update my phrasing to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying to apply a new index on a column who's name is set to be modified in the same query. So replace this:

```
ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo, bar)
```

with this:

```
ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo2, bar)
```

---

Now, about trying your separate steps: change the column name first and after that apply the `ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo, bar)`. What do you you receive? An error.

Now, reverse the steps. What's happening? It works, as you already said.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't expect it to look at the end result, but that does make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:::

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
  DROP INDEX test_table_foo_idx
  DROP INDEX test_table_bar_idx
  CHANGE COLUMN foo foo2 VARCHAR(127)
  MODIFY COLUMN foo2 TEXT
  ADD INDEX test_table_composite_idx (foo2, bar)
```